# Running Count of Non-Zero Values in pd Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to calculate the "running count" of non zero values in a pandas data frame, and add it as a new column on the same dataframe.

I can use this for a running total of the values:
`df['running_total'] = df.groupby('key_id')['payment'].cumsum()`

I can use this for the running count:
`df['trans_counts'] = df.groupby('key_id')['payment'].cumcount()`

However, this count will include the non-zero 'payment' entries, and will just give me a running total of the key_id groups.  How can we modify the cumcount() functionality to not increment when it sees a zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `cumsum`

```
df['running_total'] = df['payment'].ne(0).groupby(df['key_id']).cumsum()
```